# Place multiple numpy arrays into a larger array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, slice

I wish to create a large array and replace some of the values with two other arrays.  Each assignment works independently but the second statement overrides the first.  I wish to see both images in the background plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#initialize the arrays
img1 = np.random.rand(400,400)
img2 = np.arange(0,10000).reshape((100,100))
background = np.zeros(shape = (1600, 1600))

#embed the background with the 1st image
background[0:img1.shape[0], 0:img1.shape[1]] = img1

#place the other image somewhere else in the array
background[500:(100+500), 500:(100+500)] = img2

#plot the results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize = (5,5))
ax[0].imshow(img1, cmap = 'rainbow') 
ax[1].imshow(img2, cmap = 'rainbow') 
ax[2].imshow(background, cmap = 'rainbow') 

plt.show()
```

Comment: @roganjosh I don't understand your complaint, the title makes perfect sense for the question

Comment: @BenGrossmann "I wish to see both images in the background plot." sorry?

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, and the way that the asker is building a composite image (of the two images that are meant to show within the background plot) *is by placing the corresponding numpy arrays into a larger array*.

Comment: @BenGrossmann great, that's totally searchable. I want to work with images... "best search how to make big arrays from multiple smaller ones". In any case, you've answered and I don't have much more to add

Comment: @roganjosh First of all, there's a difference between "this title is not searchable" and your hyperbolic implication that the title is completely irrelevant. Second, the asker guessed (incorrectly) that the primary issue here was that values within the array were being overwritten; if that were the issue at hand, then this post would indeed be more likely to be relevant to somebody combining numpy arrays than it would be to somebody working with images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that "the second statement overrides the first". The problem (i.e. the reason that you're only seeing one of the images within the composite image) is that the entries in image 2 are much larger than those of image 1. When you show img1 alone, the colormap fits the colors over a scale from 0 to (approximately) 1. When the two images are shown together, the colors are scaled from 0 to 10000, so the values from img1 are all too close to zero for the image to show up.

Here's a change to your code that scales the values of the second array down to a maximum value of 1; note that both images show up this time.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#initialize the arrays
img1 = np.random.rand(400,400)
img2 = np.arange(0,10_000).reshape((100,100))/10_000
background = np.zeros(shape = (800, 800))

#embed the background with the 1st image
background[0:img1.shape[0], 0:img1.shape[1]] = img1

#place the other image somewhere else in the array
background[500:(100+500), 500:(100+500)] = img2

#plot the results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize = (5,5))
ax[0].imshow(img1, cmap = 'rainbow') 
ax[1].imshow(img2, cmap = 'rainbow') 
ax[2].imshow(background, cmap = 'rainbow') 

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

---

Incidentally, if you want to combine arrays on a zero "background" in this manner, you might want to consider using the `scipy.linalg.block_diag` method. For instance,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

#initialize the arrays
img1 = np.random.rand(400,400)
img2 = np.arange(0,10_000).reshape((100,100))/10_000

space1 = np.zeros([100,100])
space2 = np.zeros([100,100])

composite = block_diag(img1, space1, img2, space2)

#plot the results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize = (5,5))
ax[0].imshow(img1, cmap = 'rainbow') 
ax[1].imshow(img2, cmap = 'rainbow') 
ax[2].imshow(composite, cmap = 'rainbow') 

plt.show()
```

Comment: OMG! SMH! Thank you. I should have seen that.